# Angular JS Application Failed to Calculate Right Grand Total

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am consuming  Wcf Service into Angular JS Application. I am trying to Grad Total at bottom row .I want  to add every rows values and the column i want to add name is Amount as shown in screen shot. It is not calculating the right total when i run the application.

Here is the Script Code ..

```
var app = angular.module("WebClientModule", [])

    .controller('Web_Client_Controller', ["$scope", 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {

        $scope.OperType = 1;
        $scope.Account_Number = "";
        $scope.Account_Holder_Name = "";
        $scope.Amount = "";
        $scope.Sort_Code = "";
        $scope.Transcation_Type = "";
        $scope.Date = "";

        GetAllRecords();
        //To Get All Records  
        function GetAllRecords() {
            var promiseGet = myService.getAllStudent();
            promiseGet.then(function (pl) { $scope.Users = pl.data },
                function (errorPl) {
                    $log.error('Some Error in Getting Records.', errorPl);
                });
        }
        $scope.grandTotal = function () {
            return $scope.Users.reduce(function (ac, cr) {
                return ac.Amount + cr.Amount;
            });
        }


    }]);



app.service("myService", function ($http) {

    this.getAllStudent = function () {
        return $http.get("http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/GetCreateCurrentAccountDepositList");
    }
})
```

Here is the HTML code ..

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html data-ng-app="WebClientModule">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>TotalDeposit</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/RegistrationScript/DepositTotal.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <table  ng-init="items.total = {}" id="tblContainer" data-ng-controller="Web_Client_Controller">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="border: solid 2px Green; padding: 5px;">
                    <tr style="height: 30px; background-color: skyblue; color: maroon;">
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Account Number</th>
                        <th>Account Holder Name</th>

                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Sort Code</th>
                        <th>Transcation Type</th>
                        <th>Date</th>

                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tbody data-ng-repeat="user in Users">
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><span>{{user.Account_Number}}</span></td>
                            <td><span>{{user.Account_Holder_Name}}</span></td>
                            <td><span>{{user.Amount}}</span></td>

                            <td><span>{{user.Sort_Code}}</span></td>

                            <td><span>{{user.Transcation_Type}}</span></td>
                            <td><span>{{user.Date}}</span></td>

                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Total:</td>

                        <td>{{grandTotal()}}</td>

                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>



    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the screen shot when i run the application[image: Click here to see the out put]

Comment: What is the data type of `$scope.Users.Amount`? Is it a `string` or a `number`?

Comment: Amount is string

Comment: In that care you are doing string concatenation instead of addition. You need to convert the strings to numbers.

Comment: where in wcf or in angula js?

Comment: In Angular. I updated my answer to show what I am talking about.

Comment: Why are the dates shown in different formats?

Comment: because it was entered manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$scope.Users.Amount` is a string type and so you are doing string concatenation instead of addition. Convert the values to a number before you add them together. `parseFloat()` is what you'll need. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseFloat

Also, in your reduce function, since you are dealing with objects and you want a number value, you need to seed it with a 0 value to begin with. The first time the function is called `ac` will not be defined. I've updated the variable names in the `reduce()` function to clearly show what is being passed in as arguments.

```
    $scope.grandTotal = function () {
        return $scope.Users.reduce(function (previousTotal, user) {
            return previousTotal + parseFloat(user.Amount);
        }, 0); // Send in 0 as the default previousTotal
    }
```

Comment: You should leave Amount as a number then instead of converting it to a string. But your `reduce()` function still needs to be updated to leave `ac` how it is.

Comment: And your angular `reduce()` function as been updated to reflect my changes?

Comment: I updated my answer with a snippet that demonstrates the `reduce()` function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160153/discussion-between-stephen-and-mohammad).

Comment: Copy and paste this in your angular to overwrite your current $scope.grandTotal code and let me know if it works:

`$scope.grandTotal = function () {
        return $scope.Users.reduce(function (previousTotal, user) {
            return previousTotal + parseFloat(user.Amount);
        }, 0); // Send in 0 as the default previousTotal
    }`

Comment: But you don't need the user information in the script file. Its only the `$scope.Users.reduce()` function that needed to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

One problem could be that `$scope.Users` is undefined until `myService.getAllStudent()` resolves. Thus you are trying to call `.reduce` on `undefined`. One way you could remedy this is to return 'loading' or something like that until `$scope.Users` is set:

```
$scope.grandTotal = function () {
  if(!$scope.Users) {
    return 'loading';
  }

  return $scope.Users.reduce(function (ac, cr) {
    return ac.Amount + cr.Amount;
  });
}
```

Comment: sorry same result